# Induce Metric From Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Given any topological space $(X, T)$,
can we induce a metric $d$ on $X$, such that the set of all open sets in the metric space $(X, d)$ is equal to the set $T$?

Just trying to grab the intuition behind topological spaces.

Comment: Not all topological spaces are metrizable (though any metric induces a topology)

Comment: If $X$ is metrizable, yes. But that's not the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Below I'll focus on **metrizable** topologies - plenty of spaces fail to come from any metric whatsoever, but here I want to discuss the inability to "pick out" a specific metric even when we know that one exists. For example, as Kavi Rama Murthy observes every metrizable topology is Hausdorff, or phrased in the contrapositive we can't hope to get a metric from a non-Hausdorff topology.*

*I'm choosing to focus on this aspect of the question because of the word "induce" - this generally signifies a choice of object which is somehow "canonical," and the point I want to make here is that this aspect is difficult (to put it mildly!) even if we sidestep the metrizability issue.*

---

Certainly we can't hope to do so in a *unique* way, except in the trivial case of the one-point space (or the zero-point space if you allow that): we can always scale a metric by an arbitrary positive factor without changing the topology.

Precisely, given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a positive $\alpha$ consider the new function $$d_\alpha(x,y)=\alpha d(x,y).$$ This is a metric on $X$ and generates the same topology as $d$, but - as long as $X$ has at least $2$ elements - we have $d_\alpha\not=d$.

Of course this is in a sense pretty silly. A better sense of the gap between topologies and metrics can be gotten by considering some concrete examples. For example, in the context of $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have:

- The usual Euclidean metric $d((a,b),(c,d))=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$.
- The "taxicab" metric $d_{taxi}((a,b),(c,d))=\vert a-c\vert + \vert b-d\vert$.
- The "square" metric $d_{square}((a,b),(c,d))=\max\{\vert a-c\vert, \vert b-d\vert\}$.

These are genuinely different$^1$ metrics - consider in each case the ball centered on the origin with radius $1$ - but they all generate the usual topology.

---

$^1$What exactly do I mean by this? Well, I'm deliberately being a bit vague here, but one observation we can make is that none is a "scaling" of any other.

But we can say more: there are fairly simple geometric differences we can see between the metrics. For example:

- We can think about *decompositions* of squares/diamonds versus circles. In the Euclidean metric we can never write a given closed ball with positive radius as a union of four closed balls which overlap only on their boundaries - but we *can* do this in the taxicab and square metrics.
- We can also think about *corners* of squares/diamonds versus circles. In both the taxicab and square metrics, we can show that given a nonempty open ball $B$ there are exactly four points $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ (the corners) such that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ and each $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ the intersection of the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered on $c_i$ with $B$ is itself an open ball. But no such points exist for the Euclidean metric (the intersection of two circles is never a circle).

*As a fun problem, think about why I haven't described any "simple geometric" way to distinguish the taxicab and square metrics from each other ...*

Answer (score 0):

No. Topologies induced by metrics have several special properties. For example, metric topologies are Hausdorff. The indiscrete topology on $\mathbb R$ is an example of  a topological for which there is no metric.